# correct RDF-a 1.1 schema for therapist practices

Tags: schema.org, rdfa

I'm trying to find the correct schema for a mental health therapist who works in several practices. As we know, pretty much the only professional health service schema.org seems to have heard of are 'Medical Services' …

Let me outline how I've been setting up as the schema definition:

```html
<div vocab="https://schema.org">

    <div resource="https://example.com/practice.phtml" typeOf="Organization">
        <span property="name">main practice</span>
        <!-- looks like there's no other information required, data testing tool doesn't complain -->
    </div>

    <div resource="https://example.com/practice-01.phtml" typeOf="LocalBusiness">
        <meta property="parentOrganization" resource="https://example.com/practice.phtml">
        <span property="name">Practice #1</span>
            <link property="additionalType" href="https://schema.org/HealthAndBeautyBusiness">
            <link property="additionalType" href="https://schema.org/MedicalBusiness">
            <link property="additionalType" href="https://schema.org/ProfessionalService">
            <link property="additionalType" href="http://www.productontology.org/id/Psychotherapy">

        Located at
        <div property="address" typeOf="PostalAddress">
            <span property="streetAddress">Street 1</span>,
            <span property="postalCode">12345</span>,
            <span property="addressLocality">City 1</span>.
            <span property="addressCountry">SE</span>.
        </div>
        Phone: <span property="telephone">+431234567</span>
        <div property="image" content="https://example.com/img/practice01.jpg"></div>
        <div property="priceRange" content="$$"></div>
    </div>

    <div resource="https://example.com/practice-02.phtml" typeOf="LocalBusiness">
        <meta property="parentOrganization" resource="https://example.com/practice.phtml">
        <span property="name">Practice #2</span>
        Located at
        <div property="address" typeOf="PostalAddress">
            <span property="streetAddress">Street 2</span>,
            <span property="postalCode">98765</span>,
            <span property="addressLocality">City 2</span>.
            <span property="addressCountry">SE</span>.
        </div>
        Phone: <span property="telephone">+431234567</span>
        <div property="image" content="https://example.com/img/practice02.jpg"></div>
        <div property="priceRange" content="$$"></div>
    </div>

<div>
```

Google's structured data testing tool accepts it in this form, however, I wonder why no other information for the 'main' practice is required? Also,
a) whether my `additionalType` definition would allow search engines to guess the kind of offered services correctly and if
b) they would be displayed at the correct addresses on the map (yes, I'll add map coordinates also, just wanted to avoid bloated code up there).

Comment: Google only requires properties for their search-related features (e.g., a rich result). Which feature do you expect to get displayed in this context?

Comment: if someone looks for a practice, the information should be displayed as rich card instead of the one defined in 'Google Business' (as it does now) I hoped, as it allows me to define more details and update information right on the website instead of having to maintain it at Google Business.